# Reversing the Z-Order of all controls on a form

Tags: .net, winforms, z-order

I'm trying to make screenshots of certain forms that are open in an application. These forms may be covered/obscured by other open forms. Using CopyFromScreen isn't practical. Using *DrawToBitmap* on the form level gets me very close to where I want to be.

One [issue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) with using *DrawToBitmap* with a control is that:

> Controls inside containers are rendered in reverse order.

**Symptoms:**
Form A has Control B and Control C on it. If Control B is in front of Control C when *DrawToBitmap* is called on Form A, it will first draw Control B and then draw Control C. Since Control C is drawn over top of Control B, the resulting bitmap looks like Control C is in front of Control B.

My current plan is to:

1. Call *SuspendLayout*
2. Recursively reverse the Z-Order of all controls on the form
3. Call *ResumeLayout*
4. Call *DrawToBitmap*, which will create an image showing the correct order
5. Execute steps 1, 2, and 3 once more to put everything back the way it was before.

Does that sound about right?

I'm pretty sure I can use *ctrl.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(ctrl)* to get the current Z-Order index and then do a similar call with *SetChildIndex* to set it to a new value.

Now I'm looking for code samples that might help me accomplish the re-ordering part in as efficient of a manner as possible.

Comment: I don't think reversing z-order for all controls on the form, and back, is efficient to start with.

Comment: @Neolisk, how would you recommend accomplishing this, then? The goal is to have the image of the control (in this case a form) match what's visible to the user. With just a normal call to DrawToBitmap without the re-ordering, there are design elements (normally unnoticed or hidden from the user) that will show in the image, often overlapping other relevant/important form contents.

Comment: Could you update your question with how it looks now (i.e. without reordering) and how you want it to look? I am having trouble visualizing your comment. :) Also, not clear about your ultimate goal - are you trying to take a screenshot of your form?

Comment: Yes, @Neolisk. Ultimately, it will be a screenshot of the form. There are some scenarios where CopyFromScreen isn't ideal, so DrawToBitmap is needed.

Comment: Can't you just negate all z-order?

Comment: @SimonMourier, can you elaborate?

Comment: 1 -> -1, 2 -> -2, 3 -> -3, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier: ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Control).OrderBy(Function(c) Me.Controls.GetChildIndex(c))
  ctl.BringToFront()
Next
```

And then run same thing again, to revert it back:

If you have nested controls on your form, you might want to [linearise this tree into an array](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/vbnet-get-all-controls-of-specified-type-from-controlcollection-tree), for easier processing (i.e. no need for recursion).

Comment: Unless the Controls collection is inherently sorted by z-order, this doesn't seem like it would work. Assume Control B is in front of Control A which is in front of Control C. There's nothing in the above code that ensures Control B gets sent to the back, then Control A, then Control C (which would be the reverse Z-Order).

Comment: When I change the "Me" reference to a reference to the form itself where the controls are, it results in a compile error of: 'OrderBy' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'  If I leave it as "Me", the error is because "Controls" isn't a member in the class where my code is called from.

Comment: @KevinFairchild: Are you sure you have `System.Linq` in your references? Technically speaking, `OrderBy` is not a member of `System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection` - it is an extension method, which works on any IEnumerable. Which framework version are you using? Can you do `OrderBy` on an array of `String`s?

Comment: I've got "Imports System.Linq" for that class, but that's it. Yes, though, I can do an OrderBy on a String array.

Comment: @Kevin: Yep, sorry - just tested and got same error. Please see my another edit, notice `.OfType(Of Control)` got added.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. The only extra thing I did was to add a recursive call if ctrl.HasChildren